# how to unit test fallback function using solidity by passing data

Tags: fallback-function, unittesting

```
fallback() external payable {
    bytes calldata data = msg.data;
    bytes memory lendId =bytes(data[msg.data.length-32:]); //last parameter must be lendingId
    uint256 _lendingId = uint256(abi.decode(lendId,(uint256)));
    require(proxyOwner == msg.sender,"caller must be owner");
    require(IEmber(stakingAddress).rentedTill(_lendingId)> block.timestamp, "Rent duration Expired");
    address adapter = IEmber(stakingAddress).checkNFTAdapter(_lendingId);

    assembly {
        // copy function selector and any arguments
        calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize())
         // execute function call using the adapter
        let result := delegatecall(gas(), adapter, 0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)
        // get any return value
        returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
        // return any return value or error back to the caller
        switch result
            case 0 {
                revert(0, returndatasize())
            }
            default {
                return(0, returndatasize())
            }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: It will be easier testing from another contract that checks the returned message is correct.